# Conda and python are misconfigured, not sure what is wrong

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to setup a local conda environment and ran `conda create -n hw3 python=3` and `source activate hw3`. It seems from running `conda info` things are working. However when I try to run `python --version`, I get Python 2.7 even though I expect 3.6 and I'm not sure why. Any ideas? I suspect path problems but not sure what's wrong. My `$PATH` is this: `/Users/michael/miniconda3/envs/hw3/bin:/Users/michael/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS`

[image]

Comment: your `os` or `some module` use `python27`, check all `path` variants !

Comment: Please do not post code in images. Search engines cannot index this information, so no one else can find the post, and blind users can't read the information at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently running `conda install python=3.6` makes the conda env work and points `python` to `Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.`

It also installed the `py36_1` version of `pip` which is nice. That way the whole environment was on the same page (same version of Python).